# How to align vertically tikz nodes with rotate

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, vertical-alignment

How do I align tikz nodes which are rotated?

[image: how to align these nodes?]

```
\documentclass{beamer}            
\usepackage{tikz}                                                        
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,matrix,fit,tikzmark}

\begin{document}                                                         
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Flow}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                      
  \node (doc) {Doc};
  \node[draw, trapezium, rotate=90, right=.5cm of doc, anchor=north] (step1) {reductin step 1};
  \node[draw, trapezium, rotate=90, right=.5cm of step1, anchor=north] (step2) {reduction step 2};
  \node[draw, right= of step2, text width=2cm] (step3) {Non-reducing};   
  \node[draw, text width=4cm, right= of step3] (comment) {Long comment:\\all nodes should aligned by their vertical centers};

  \draw[->] (doc) to (step1); 
  \draw[->] (step1) to (step2);
  \draw[->] (step2) to (step3);                 
  \draw[->] (step3) to (comment);                                                                                                                 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are almost there. Just add `.south` twice after `step1` and `step2`: `\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=90, right=.5cm of step1.south, anchor=north] (step2) {reduction step 2};
  \node[draw, right= of step2.south, text width=2cm] (step3) {Non-reducing};`.

Comment: Your solution worked and now I see why. Would you like to answer or I do?

Comment: Whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to use south anchor because, although rotate, node's anchors do not change:

```
\documentclass{beamer}            
\usepackage{tikz}                                                        
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,matrix,fit,tikzmark}

\begin{document}                                                         
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Flow}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                      
  \node (doc) {Doc};
  \node[draw, trapezium, rotate=90, right=.5cm of doc, anchor=north] (step1) {reductin step 1};
  \node[draw, trapezium, rotate=90, right=.5cm of step1.south, anchor=north] (step2) {reduction step 2};
  \node[draw, right= of step2.south, text width=2cm] (step3) {Non-reducing};   
  \node[draw, text width=4cm, right= of step3] (comment) {Long comment:\\all nodes should aligned by their vertical centers};

  \draw[->] (doc) to (step1); 
  \draw[->] (step1) to (step2);
  \draw[->] (step2) to (step3);                 
  \draw[->] (step3) to (comment);                                                                                                                 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Following @Schrödinger's cat 's good idea.